# How do I merge two functions with common IN OUT parameters and get two return values from it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Functions are-

```
Function 1(a in varchar, b in number, c in varchar)
return number as
aaa varchar;
bbb number;
begin
select name into aaa from tb1 where w1;
return aaa;
exception
eee
end;

function 2 (b in number)
return number as
bbb number;

begin
select address into bbb from tb2 where w2;
return bbb;
exception
eee
end;
```

So basically function 2 is a sub set of function 1. But written seperately. I wish to merge them and get two values and how should they be called to get the desired value only, not both.

Comment: Very unclear. Where do you use any of the IN parameters in Function 1? Where do you use the IN parameter in Function 2? What do you mean by "where w1"? - that looks like an incomplete condition.

Answer (score 0):

To return 2 values, function should return [collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html) of numbers instead one number (the are many options for return value: it can by concatenated string, cursor, or temporary table, it depends on code requirements).

To use collection result in other sql or pl/sql statements, it must be declared as type on schema level.

In example of code below:

1. create collection type **f1f2_array** - to keep result from both **f1** and **f2** functions
2. create functions **f1**, **f2** and **f1f2** - it call both **f1** and **f2** and return collection **f1f2_array** result
3. pl/sql check block - call **f1f2** and print result

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE type f1f2_array AS TABLE OF NUMBER
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1 RETURN NUMBER AS
   BEGIN
     RETURN 1;
   END;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2 RETURN NUMBER AS
   BEGIN
     RETURN 2;
   END;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1f2 RETURN f1f2_array AS
     v_res f1f2_array := f1f2_array();
   BEGIN
     v_res.extend(2);
     v_res(1) := f1;
     v_res(2) := f2;
     RETURN v_res;
   END;
   /

   /* check */
   set SERVEROUTPUT ON;

   DECLARE
     v_array f1f2_array;
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('result from f1 and f2:');
     v_array := f1f2;
     FOR i IN 1..v_array.count
     LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('f'||i||'='||v_array(i));
     END LOOP;
   END;
   /
   ```

Comment: This looks great! Thank you!!